# Can you join a game that's further into the plot than your character?

Tags: borderlands-2

Is it possible for another player(player 2) to join a nearly complete game of borderlands 2 to (for example) defeat a boss?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they can, although weapon damage ramps up at an exponential rate, so unless player 2 is close to or above the same level as player 1, they won't be much help against the boss.

Comment: If he stays (relatively) out of the fight though, wouldn't P2 get the mountain of experience that comes with defeating higher level enemies?

Comment: @Robotnik Yes, although it's not as much as you might think. A month or two ago, I, as a level 24, joined two level 50s in killing Vermivorous the Invincible a few times. After killing him 5 or six times, I think I was level 28. While I didn't completely stay out, I certainly wasn't helping much. My criticals were doing 48 damage. As Zero.

Comment: If you're in it for the xp, the warrior goes a lot faster, he gives about the same amount of xp, but he dies a lot faster. Unless you use the infinity pistol glitch ofcourse.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, although if the second player has never played before, he will be level 1 and will most likely get killed very fast by those high level enemies.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and you may want to see [How does mission progress work in multiplayer?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/85136/1134) which discusses how plot/mission progression works. Also, [How does experience work in co-op?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/85071/1134)