# Co-Op partner leveling faster than I do in Borderlands 2

Tags: xbox-360, borderlands-2

I am playing *Borderlands 2* in Co-Op with my husband.  We have been playing everything together and don't play these charters without the other, but he is leveling faster than me. It started just as a little more than me and now at level 63 he is almost a whole level ahead. Anyone know why? He doesn't have anything equipped that would give him more experience.

Answer (score 8):

Aside from experience boosting equipment there are three factors that can lead to diverging experience.

- +100xp for reviving an ally is personal. Do you go down often?
- You may be falling behind when your partner kills enemies. There is a certain maximum distance from the kill (or killing player) that experience gets awarded. I use to lead my wife's character along when she goes AFK to the baby.
- The player dealing the killing blow gets a slightly greater amount of experience. If your husband deals more damage, he'll get this bonus more often.

Other than that, experience is shared equally (copied, actually).

More info in this question: [How does experience work in co-op?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84869/how-does-experience-work-in-co-op)

+1 for family gaming!

Comment: Well that explains it. He definitely gets more kills than I do. I will phaselock and he usually finishes them off, plus his Gunzerker wrecks house while I manage to hold my own with the Siren. I actually revive him more with my resurrect skill but obviously not enough to make up the difference. Thanks for answer @Orc JMR!

Comment: Family Gaming Rocks!

Comment: @DevonHayzlett We play a Gunzerker and a Siren too :) By the way, you can accept the answer that helped you the most to mark the question as answered - see a checkmark below answer's score.

Answer (score 0):

Who is doing more damage/killing? Often, it is the person who gets the killing blow or does the most damage that gets the majority of the experience points (the skew being dependent on the game).

It's been a while since I played *Borderlands 2*, but I think the person doing the kill gets a slightly higher bit of EXP, so I would assume this to be the general reason. Also check his skill tree to see if he has a small EXP booster there.

Comment: Yes he does do more damage and killing, which would explain the wider the gap has gotten throughout the game. Thanks @CyberSkull!