# How are experience points divided between players in Borderlands?

Tags: borderlands

We're playing Borderlands among a small group of friends and I've noticed we tend to level up in a ever-so-slightly staggered fashion. It's no single character or player, I think so far everyone in our party has been the first to reach a  given level one big fight before the rest.

The characters aren't being played outside our multiplayer party, which means experience gain must be somehow uneven between characters. How are experience points from killing monsters divided between players? Is there a last-hit or assist bonus or something like that?

Comment: @Timelord64 VTLO. Just because the experience systems in different games in the same series may be similar does not mean they are duplicate questions. In fact, the experience systems are different! BL2 divides exp evenly; BL1 doesn't.

Comment: Absolutely right. I misread this as borderlands 2. Thanks for the correction @Schism, much obliged

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Borderlands, the player who gets the last hit gets full experience, while other players get only partial experience for the kill.

More detailed information here: [How does experience work in co-op?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84869/how-does-experience-work-in-co-op). The majority of it applies to all Borderlands games.

A tidbit of info I just remembered: The achieves give experience, so unlocking different achievements at different intervals will cause fluctuation as well.

Comment: Cheers! Would you also happen to know how large the other players' portion is?

Comment: IIRC it will be half, but that's mostly an educated guess. I would validate more, but I'm at work and it's hard to justify browsing game sites.

Comment: Wanted to mention, if you have all the combat text turned on, you can see how much exp you get from a kill. Just have your buddies stand around when you kill something and record how much everyone gets. It'll be easy to calculate from there.

Comment: Great answer! But your referenced question looks to be identical to this one..

Answer (score -1):

If there is a level difference among players, the EXP will be distributed accordingly so the lowest level character gets the highest and the higher level character gets the lowest. It does not matter who gives the killing blow.

That being said what you may be seeing is some of the people in your party may be completing challenges and gaining bonus EXP since it's a personal EXP reward, and is not distributes among the party.